# Report appendix equations in a section

Tags: equations, numbering, appendix

How can I report an equation that is written in the Appendix, say with numbering A.1, into the body of a section using the SAME numbering?
For example, if it is Section 3, I don't want it to be displayed with the numbering 3.1 etc., but precisely with A.1

Comment: A manual way is adding `\tag{}`, i.e., `\begin{equation} x=y+1 \tag{A.1}\label{eq: 3.1} \end{equation}`

Comment: Try labelling it in the appendix, and use `\tag{\ref{eq-label}}` in the section.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you're using a document class that's compatible with the `amsmath` package. (Fortunately, most document classes satisfy this criterion.) I suggest you use the `\numberwithin` macro of the `amsmath` package to set the numbering style and the `\tag` macro to override the default numbering system for selected equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\tag" and "\numberwithin" macros
\numberwithin{equation}{section} % set numbering style

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2} % just for this example
\section{Third Section}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2 \tag{\ref{eq:trivial}} % use "\tag" to override the default numbering method
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:also-trivial} % employ default numbering method
0+0=0
\end{equation}

\appendix % change section "numbers" to "A", "B", ...
\section{Additional Results}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:trivial}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I use the book documentclass and it works very well! Thank you!